# Which JSlint I should be using?

Tags: javascript, unix, jslint

I have searched in old question. Everyone is giving different suggestion for jslint utility. 
I want jslint console utility which works on linux console. 
I tried this one 
http://www.javascriptlint.com/ but it don't work properly. One example 
it don't give error if you missed writing `var` before variable declaration.

Is there any standard command line utility for jslint?

**Edit**

I tried https://github.com/reid/node-jslint this also works good. But don't know if it is recommended.

**About jshint**

```
  client.on('JOB_CREATED', function(handle) {
    sessionid=[];
    return console.log('job created', handle);
    //Do connection close and cleanup                                                                                                                  

  });
```

Why it is not giving error for `sessionid=[];`

Comment: http://www.jshint.com/install/

Comment: @SLaks JShint don't give error. if I miss writing var before variable declaration. Am I missing any setting ?

Comment: just don't use jshint

Comment: the question is about what to use instead. I actually use JSLint(the base for node-jslint?), but as the question is special to console: i don't know. Also JSHint does not force a code style, which for me feels better when working with multiple people on a project. JSLint on the other side is written by Crockford and does stop(will not process the rest of the file) on errors like `for(var i = 1;` which is very annoying, when you never reuse that variable anyways.

Answer (score 0):

2¢ -- Yes, as you've added, if you want to run jslint on the command line, Node is currently the way to do it.  So you've answered your own question.

For which JSLint package, I don't see anything particularly *wrong* about reid's implementation.  Check out [its code](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/blob/master/lib/nodelint.js):

```
/*jslint
    nomen: true
 */
var vm = require("vm");
var fs = require("fs");

var ctx = vm.createContext();

vm.runInContext(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/jslint.js"), ctx);

module.exports = ctx.JSLINT;
```

That looks fine.  Not that it means much, but `npm info jslint` points you to the same package, so you're okay, though there *are* a number of others... `npm search jslint` pops up a good number, many of which are command-line jslinters.

I want to say I've heard of [`JSLintCli`](https://github.com/rodrigok/Node-JSLint) before, but if reid's is working, it's more recently updated.  JSLinting with Node is a simple enough process that you're going to be fine.  Would be fun to write your own wrapper.